# How can I create a backup of composer/bower vendor packages before updating?

Tags: php, composer-php

I need to update an outdated Symfony 2.8 project that uses composer and bower as package managers.

The problem is that the website may not go down, but because the project is outdated I fear composer or bower will fail in the update process, causing the website to go down.

I know I can run composer in a dry run mode, and that I'll do before actually updating:

```
composer update --dry-run
composer install --dry-run
```

But I want to be absolutely sure I can revert the vendor packages whenever problems occur. So I thought I could simply make a backup tar:

```
cd /home/project/public_html/
tar cvf /home/project/composer_bower`date +'%Y%m%d'`.tar composer.json composer.lock bower.json .bowerrc vendor/ web/assets/vendor/
```

Is this the way I should make a backup of the vendor packages? Composer does not seem to have a built-in possibility to revert an update/install. Are there other options?

Comment: Put `*.lock` under version control? That should allow to revert to the exact dependencies. As long as you are not modifying packages locally... If you need to revert, you _should_ have the packages already cached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not composer's job to do this.

It's up to you to version control `composer.*` files (and any other dependency declaration file, like `symfony.lock` if you are working under Symfony.

Or even to be safer, to create copies of complete artefacts from dependency declaration + retrieved dependencies (e.g. code + `vendor` directory).

On some of our projects, where that kind of sensitivity is required, every deployment is a fully contained and versioned image. If something goes wrong with a deployment, we can always go back a on old image.

On less critical projects, just putting dependency declaration files on version control might be enough.